# isomorphism of two localized ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an algebraic closed field, $K[X,Y]$ be it's polynomial ring, $K[X,Y]/\langle XY\rangle=A$ be a quotient ring. Let $f=[X]\in A$, define $S=\{f^{n}|n\in\mathbb{N_{0}}\}$. Also define $T=\{X^{n}|n\in\mathbb{N_{0}}\}$, then show that $S^{-1}A$ isomorphic to $T^{-1}K[X]$.

I have problem finding the isomorphism. $S^{-1}A$ spanned by $Y^{n}X^{-m},n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $X^{p}, p\in\mathbb{N_{0}}$, while $T^{-1}K[X]$ spanned by $X^{q}, q\in\mathbb{Z}$. The degree of freedom isn't the same, how can it be possible to be isomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that $\{[x]^n\}^{-1}A\cong\{x^n\}^{-1}K[x]$.

Consider the natural morphism given by mapping $\frac{[f(x,y)]}{[x]^n}$ to $\frac{f(x,0)}{x^n}$, then try to prove this map is well-defined and is an isomorphism of rings. This is not difficult.